# PHP and redis in same docker image

Tags: docker

I'm trying to add redis to a php:7.0-apache image, using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install build-essential tcl

RUN cd /tmp \
    && curl -O http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz \
    && tar xzvf redis-stable.tar.gz \
    && cd redis-stable \
    && make \
    && make install


COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY public /var/www/html/

RUN chown -R root:www-data /var/www/html
RUN chmod -R 1755 /var/www/html
RUN find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 1775 {} +

RUN mkdir -p /var/redis/6379
COPY 6379.conf /etc/redis/6379.conf
COPY redis_6379 /etc/init.d/redis_6379

RUN chmod 777 /etc/init.d/redis_6379

RUN update-rc.d redis_6379 defaults
RUN service apache2 restart
RUN service redis_6379 start
```

It build and run fines but redis is never started? When I run /bin/bash inside my container and manually input "service redis_6379 start" it works, so I'm assuming my .conf and init.d files are okay.

While I'm aware it'd much easier using docker-compose, I'm specifically trying to avoid having to use it for specific reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong here:

- Starting processes in dockerfile has no effect. A dockerfile builds an image. The processes need to be started at container construction time. This can be done using an entrypoint can be defined in the dockerfile by using `ENTRYPOINT`. That entrypoint is typically a script that is executed when an actual container is started.
- There is no init process in docker by default. Issuing `service` calls will fail without further work. If you need to start multiple processes you can look for the docs of the supervisord program.
- Running both redis and a webserver in one container is not best practice. For a php application using redis you'd typically have 2 containers - one running redis and one running apache and let them interact via network.

I suggest you read the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/) before continuing. All this is described in depth there.

Comment: Thanks for your info, I went with supervisord. Also, as I said in my post, I know using multiple containers is the better way, but I'm not doing that on purpose as a proof of concept. It's more of a learning experience than anything else, it's not going to production, ever.

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with @Richard. Use two or more containers according to your needs then --link them, in order to get the things work!

Comment: As I said in my post, I know it's the better way, but I'm not doing that on purpose as a proof of concept. It's more of a learning experience than anything else, it's not going to production, ever.